# Deserializing a json array into a object C# using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

I have some JSON returning from an API that is in the form of

```
[
    {
        "param1":"value",
        "param2":"value2",
        ...
    },
    {
        "param1":"value",
        "param2":"value2",
         ...
    }
]
```

I have a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the `System.Text.Json` library.

If I deserialize like this:

```
var output = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Foo>>(JsonStr)
```

all works fine and in 'output' I have a list of `Foo`.

However, I want to deserialize into another class so I can do some inheritance from a base class that can perform some checks to see if there is data and some other bits and bobs.

```
public class Bar : BarBase
{
    public List<Foo> data { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, if I try to deserialize into `Bar`, it throws an error that it cannot map the JSON to the object.

Is there any attribute that can be used to state that the JSON should map to 'data' or is there a different way to go about this?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: What's the difference between deserializing straight to `Bar` (which doesn't really represent the JSON you've shown) and `var bar = new Bar { data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Foo>>(JsonStr) };`?

Comment: I did say this was valid but then after some thought this would not work with the generics i have set up. Potentially I could rewrite some bits, but if there is an easier way i would rather do that as the rewrite would be quite a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by letting the Bar class inherit from List

```
public class Bar : List<Foo>
{
  public List<Foo> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would be other thinking it. Cannot believe I did not try this.