# Deserializing a json array into a object containing List

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I found this question/answer [Deserializing a json array into a object C# using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382143/deserializing-a-json-array-into-a-object-c-sharp-using-system-text-json). But the answer doesn't fully work for me. The issue is that once I try to access the list from inside class Bar, `data` is null.

JSON :

```
[
    {
        "param1":"value",
        "param2":"value2"
    },
    {
        "param1":"value",
        "param2":"value2"
    }
]
```

Class objects:

```
public class Bar : List<Foo>
  {
    public List<Foo> data { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach( Foo item in data )
      {
        sb.Append( item.ToString() );
      }

      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
  public class Foo
  {
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.Append( " param 1 : " +  param1 + Environment.NewLine );
      sb.Append( " param 2 : " + param2 + Environment.NewLine );

      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Calling it:

```
string? director = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
string configfile = String.Empty;

if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( director ) == false )
{
  configfile = Path.Combine( director, "ArrrayTest.txt" );
  if ( ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( configfile ) == false ) && ( File.Exists( configfile ) == true ) )
  {
    using ( StreamReader sr = File.OpenText( configfile ) )
    {
      string jsonstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
      Bar? output = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bar>( jsonstring );
      if ( output != null )
      { 
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString() );
      }
    } 
  }
```

At the line `if ( output != null )` output is not null and `data` contains two elements. But inside `output.ToString();` `data` is null.

How do I make this work, so that inside the Bar class, `data` isn't null? Why would `data` be different when accessed from outside, then when accessed from inside the object?

I'm using VS 2022, .NET 6 and System.Text.json.

Comment: Your class definition says that `Bar` _is a_ list of `Foo` but it also _has a_ list of `Foo`. Your JSON is representing the _is a_ paradigm, not the _has a_ paradigm. (It's not clear to me how the linked answer works either, maybe there's some deserialization magic that I'm not aware of)

Comment: You design of inheriting from `List<T>` and adding additional properties is going to cause lots of problems for you, not the least of which being that most serializers won't serialize the properties.  See [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/3744182) for more.  Consider changing your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `Bar` class is both a `List<Foo>` and contains a property `List<Foo> data`. This design is confusing because it's unclear where the JSON array should be deserialized to – the `Bar` object itself (since it's a `List<Foo>`) or the `data` property inside it.

When you call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bar>(jsonstring);`, the serializer tries to match the JSON array to the `Bar` class. Since `Bar` is a `List<Foo>`, it successfully populates the `Bar` instance itself with the `Foo` items from the array. However, the `data` property remains null because there's no corresponding property in the JSON array to map it to.

The solution is to clarify the design. If `Bar` should contain the list, then it shouldn't inherit from `List<Foo>`. If `Bar` should inherit from `List<Foo>`, then you don't need the `data` property.

Here's how you can adjust your `Bar` class:

Option 1: Remove inheritance and use the `data` property only.

```cs
public class Bar
{
  // No longer inheriting from List<Foo>
  public List<Foo> data { get; set; } = new List<Foo>();  // Initialize so it's never null

  public override string ToString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Foo item in data)  // Now it uses the 'data' property
    {
      sb.Append(item.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

With this option, you don't have to change your deserialization code. The JSON array will correctly populate the `data` property.

Option 2: Remove the `data` property and use the `Bar` class itself.

```cs
public class Bar : List<Foo>
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Foo item in this)  // 'this' refers to the Bar itself as it's a List<Foo>
    {
      sb.Append(item.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

For option 2, your calling code should work as it is, since `Bar` itself is the list, and all items in the deserialized JSON array are placed in `Bar` directly.

After adjusting your `Bar` class according to one of these options, the `data` should not be null when accessed within the `Bar` class' `ToString()` method. The confusion arises from trying to use both inheritance and a property to represent the same data.

Remember to update all other parts in your code that might depend on `Bar` being a `List<Foo>` or having a `data` property to match your chosen design.

Comment: Thank you. So Option 1 results in System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Bar.  But Option 2 works great.

Comment: Option 1 does not work because it requires that the json have a `data` property, which it does not have. An alternative would be to deserialize it to a `List<Foo>` and _assign_ that list to `data`.  Inheriting from `List` directly is generally a bad idea except in unusual circumstances.

Comment: This is a fake ChatGPT answer by a user that posted a dozen such answers in an hour